# TemplateDoesNotExist (Django)

Tags: python, django

[image: TemplateDoesNotExist][image: Структура каталогов]

Писал код и появилась такая вот проблема. Долго сидел и не мог разобраться в чём причина. Помогите пожалуйста.

Посмотрел в интернете решение и всё равно не могу разобраться что делаю не так. Файл register.html находиться в каталоге templates.

Перепроверял весь код раз 10. Возможно свежий взгляд со стороны поможет.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    # Add URL authorization
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # Page of registration
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def register(request):
    # Register new user
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Выводит пустую форму регистрации.
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        # Обработка заполненной формы.
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            # Enter and going in homepage
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('learning_logs:index')

    # Вывести пустую или недействительную форму.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My_apps
    'learning_logs',
    'users',
    # Django_apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
```

register.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:register' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button name="submit">register</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="next"
           value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}" />
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Покажите структуру каталогов и файлов в вашем проекте.

Comment: @wchistow users/templates/registration/register.html

Comment: @wchistow Добавил фото

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена и ответ оказался проще, чем я думал.
Ошибка была в этой части кода:

```
 return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

Я передавал не ту папку.
Вот правильный код:

```
return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедитесь, что у вас правильно настроены URL-маршруты и пути:
2. Проверьте, что в файле `urls.py` приложения "users" корректно определен URL-путь для регистрации. У вас уже есть `register/`, и он выглядит правильно.
3. Убедитесь, что приложение "users" включено в `INSTALLED_APPS` в файле `settings.py`.
4. Убедитесь, что файл `register.html` находится в директории `templates` вашего проекта. По умолчанию *Django* ожидает, что шаблоны будут находиться внутри директории `templates` в корне вашего проекта.
5. Проверьте, что в вашем проекте нет других файлов с именем `register.html`, которые могли бы перекрывать ваш шаблон.
6. Убедитесь, что ваш сервер *Django* запущен и работает.
7. Проверьте, не возникают ли ошибки в консоли или в журнале сервера *Django*, когда вы пытаетесь открыть страницу регистрации.
8. Если у вас есть пользовательская база данных (например, если вы настраивали другой бэкэнд аутентификации), убедитесь, что он настроен правильно.
9. Попробуйте включить режим отладки в вашем проекте *Django*, чтобы получить более подробные сообщения об ошибках. В файле `settings.py` установите `DEBUG = True`.